# What is the significance of Flash's new suit at the end of Flashpoint Paradox?

Tags: dc, the-flash, dc-animated-movie-universe, flashpoint-paradox

I don't know if this is of importance or not, but at the end of *Justice League: The Flashpoint Paradox*, Flash is wearing a new design on his suit.

Did I miss something? Is there an explanation for it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Spoilers** At the end of Flashpoint Paradox, after Flash goes back in time at the end to fix everything, all of the heroes have their costumes slightly changed because it is now the New 52 timeline. It seems really annoying but it's just a minor change now and has no real significance. It's just a costume update based on the New 52 designs so that the new comic book costumes will be used for future animated movies as well. Hope it helps!

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the explanation. :)